# Why is my converter not firing once the property is updated?

Tags: c#, wpf

To give a short description of my problem, I have a label which I want to show the contents of an ObservableCollection list in the format of "Item1, Item2, Item3, etc".

So my XAML looks like this. Code shortened for readability.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:ListToString x:Key="ToList"></c:ListToString>
</Window.Resources>

<Label x:Name="yaxisTxt" Content="{Binding Path=YAxisVariables, Converter={StaticResource ToList}}">
```

YAxisVariables is the ObservableCollection. My VM behind looks like this, again shortened.

```
class ChartVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<string> _yaxisvars;
    public ObservableCollection<string> YAxisVariables
    {
        get
        {
            return (_yaxisvars);
        }
        set
        {
            _yaxisvars = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("YAxisVariables");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string PropName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropName));
        }
    }
}
```

And my converter looks like this. I want the label to show "Drag variable" if the ObservableCollection is empty, and to show the values of the collection if it's not empty.

```
public class ListToString : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is ObservableCollection<string>)
        {
            ObservableCollection<string> vars = (ObservableCollection<string>)value;
            if (vars.Count > 0)
            {
                string series = null;
                foreach (string var in vars)
                {
                    if (series != null)
                        series = series + ", " + var;
                    else
                        series = var;
                }
                series.Trim(',');
                series.Trim(' ');

                return series;
            }
            else
                return "Drag variable";
        }

        return null;

    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when the form is loaded and the list is empty, the converter fires correctly and the label displays "Drag variable", however when the list is updated and the property changes, the converter does not fire.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I imagine that you are adding items in to the `ObservableCollection` which will not do what you desire. Rather than adding items in to the collection try creating a new collection and assigning it to your `YAxisVariables` property.

Comment: @Grx70 Yes exactly that, much better explanation :)

Comment: Ok I see why it's not firing now. Could you maybe post some code how to assign a new collection to the YAxisVariables property?

Comment: In your case the bound value is an `ObservableCollection`, and its state is not tracked by the binding engine. In order to make it re-evaluate the bound value (meaning also apply the converter) you need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `YAxisVariables` property (you actually don't even need to replace the collection, simply raising the event will do).

Comment: thanks for the tips guys, I got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

With collections there are 3 kinds of bindings/change notification you need:

1. Changes to the collection (add, remove). That is the only ones ObservableCollection takes care off
2. Change notification on the property exposing the collection. OC are notoriously bad to bulk-modify while exposed. So when you want to do bulk modifications, it is better to build it in the View Model, then expose it when fully build.
3. Change notification for every property of the class you hold in the ObservableCollection

Other things of notice:

You hardcoded the property name string. C# had syntax added so you whould never have to do that. You should definitely be using [CallerMemberName] and similar things to make your code refactoring safe and avoid mispellings.

Actually nothing ever binds to a simple collection. WPF elements only ever bind to CollectionViews. But if you give them a random collection, they do not hesistate to make a CollectionView from it. For advanced things (changing/tracking selected elements, filtering, sorting) you have to take control of that step and make the CollectionView yourself: https://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm relatively new to WPF so I'm still learning.

Comment: I figured. I had the same issue when learning MVVM myself. Actually I made a short intro into MVVM way back when I learned it. Maybe it helps you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf